# Resources on reflective cooling

Tags: cooling, solar

Preparing for the next heatwave with something more sustainable than air conditioning, I'm looking into the idea of installing cooling reflectors as promoted by the site [www.meer.org](https://www.meer.org) (basically, reflecting solar radiation with mirrors on the rooftop).
Despite the simplicity of the idea, I cannot find other resources on it, and I'd like to know how much passive cooling to expect, which I think would not be very hard if I have the insolation data of my area. All I find is longwave radiative cooling, which (this is my opinion) looks like the anthitesis of sustainable (very high tech and questionable long term reliability).
Anyone has a reference on passive cooling techniques that includes solar reflective measures?